# Get duplicate JSON Object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, duplicates, plane

I have array of JSON objects

```
[
 {"OBJECT":"S_DEVELOP","AUTH":"&_DEV_01_40","AKTPS":"A"},
 {"OBJECT":"S_DEVELOP","AUTH":"&_DEV_TMPOBJ","AKTPS":"A"},
 {"OBJECT":"S_DEVELOP","AUTH":"&_DEV_01_40","AKTPS":"A"}
]
```

from these objects I need to check if the AUTH value is common (repeated) and if any such object has an repeated AUTH value, I need to store such objects in an array.

so from the above JSON objects since the AUTH value &_DEV_01_40 is repeated , the output should be like

```
[
  {"OBJECT":"S_DEVELOP","AUTH":"&_DEV_01_40","AKTPS":"A"}, 
  {"OBJECT":"S_DEVELOP","AUTH":"&_DEV_01_40","AKTPS":"A"}
]
```

Can someone guide me how to write it in plane Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the array of objects twice. Once to find the duplicate AUTHs, and then a second time to retrieve only the objects that have duplicate AUTHs.

```
function getDuplicates(array) {
  let seen = {};

  array.forEach((obj) => {
    seen[obj["AUTH"]] = typeof seen[obj["AUTH"]] === "undefined" ? 1 : seen[obj["AUTH"]] + 1;
  });

  let duplicateKeys = Object.keys(seen).filter((key) => seen[key] > 1);

  return array.filter((obj) => duplicateKeys.indexOf(obj["AUTH"]) !== -1);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj4mu05x/4/)

Comment: Thank you. But I figured out a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: var dulObjArr = [];
    //var checkArr = [];
    for(var count=0; count<testObject.length; count++) {
        var obj = testObject[count];
        
        //checkArr.push(obj);
            for(var dupl=0; dupl<testObject.length; dupl++) {
                if(dupl!= count && testObject[dupl].AUTH === obj.AUTH) {
                    dulObjArr.push(obj);
                    break;
                }
            }
        
        
        
    }
    console.log("dulObjArr Length: " + dulObjArr.length);
    return dulObjArr;